# XSD Schema Datatypes For Systems With 32-bit Primitives?

Tags: xsd, schema, types

I just discovered (the hard way, of course) that all of the integer datatypes I'm using in my XSD schemas are allowing 64-bit values to pass validation instead of 32-bit values.  Yes, I know -- my bad for not diving deeply into the W3C specifications for datatypes and just assuming that INT would be 32-bit.

So is there an easy way (as in a DOCTYPE declaration, or a namespace, etc.) I can enforce a 32-bit limit on any "xs:" datatypes involving integers?  Right now I'm going through and declaring my own derived datatypes with 32-bit min/max values and fgrep'ing the XSD files, but it would be rather nice if there was an easy (obvious) tweak that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in [xs:int](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#int) type, which is derived from `xs:integer` and has a signed 32-bit range.

> 3.3.17 int
>
> [Definition:]   int is ·derived· from
>   long by setting the value of
>   ·maxInclusive· to be 2147483647 and
>   ·minInclusive· to be -2147483648. The
>   ·base type· of int is long.

(and the base type of xs:long is xs:integer)

Comment: Excellent!  Exactly what I was looking for, and somehow completely missed, when I was link-tracking (BNFish -- *argh!*) through the W3C spec for XML Schema!

Comment: Great. The best way to find things in the data types spec is to start at the type hierarchy diagram: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes